# Tableau R calculation on every row

Tags: r, tableau-api

I have several columns in my Table, which I want to fully send to R to perform some operations on these columns, and return a computation, which is again a vector.

I know that I have to pass aggregates to the R script in a calculated field. I do this using MAX(). 
So I found out that I should use a unique row ID and have the calculation run over this row ID, instead of accross the table ("Compute Using ...", is now a default table calculation, accross the table).
However, how can I get a unique row ID? I create a calculated field with Index(), and when I create a view with this, it is indeed a unique row ID. But I can't convert it to a dimension (which is needed for the "Compute using") because Index() is a table calculation.

Without this row ID I do not get the desired results, because it is only passing the MAX() of each column to R, I believe.

My data is of the following:
Group, Time, Number

So for group 1, I can have more rows, with multiple times and corresponding numbers. I want all of this data to go into the script.

**Edit:**

My data is as in the first three columns. I want to create a field of the fourth column. This always has to be calculated on Id and sorted Time. If there is any calculation in Tableau directly that can do this, I am also good.  I'm having a hard time passing the first three columns into R. I think I need an extra Row ID.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what your data looks like and what you want. It's much easier to understand if you provide a small example data and the expected output. You can copy-paste the output of `dput(data)` to share data

Comment: @CPak, Sorry, I added a picture of some sample data and desired output.

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot of issues - first in reading in the data, then in implementing the specific operation you're interested in. Start with obtaining help with reading in your data - then post a separate issue with the specific operation. Open-ended questions like your current post generally do not invite lots of help